# How to separate data from the arraylist and display it in to the listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

In one of my application i got the arraylist like below:

```
[android_metadata, test1, test10, test1002, test2, test3, test4, test5]
```

Now i want to separate all the data. and display it in to list view. How it can be done?
I want some code to implement it and display it in to listview in android.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to seperate the data, you can directly pass the list and show all the data in ListView.

Comment: I want to do Some operation with that data so thats why i want to separate it. Now i come to know that by using ListView position i can also able to get it.

Comment: I want to separate it because i dont want that android_metadata data as per my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array List has a method called size() and get(Index number)

1. ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
2. al.sze(); // to get size of array list
3. String item1 = al.get(index number); // to get the elemnet of array list

go to this link for more detail --->  [array list knowledge](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: But i also want to display it in to the listView then ?

Comment: You can make a new array list and add the elements you extracted from the previous array list except those which you dont want to add like meta data element.